# Auction end time triggering other actions

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I am building an auction site using ColdFusion and MySQL. Here in New Zealand, the main auction site is [www.trademe.co.nz](http://www.trademe.co.nz). On that site, once an auction expires, it displays a status of "closing", which lasts for about a minute before the auction disappears.  What sort of routine could be run, either in MySQL or ColdFusion or both, that will trigger off an auction expiry date being reached? I have heard of CRON, but from what I know this is similar to a ColdFusion scheduled task that runs at set periods. Also, it doesn't work with Windows.

BUT what seems to be needed here is something that picks up in REAL TIME that an auction has expired, rather than catching those auctions every minute, which would miss auctions that expired between times.

Hope that make sense. I am looking for an approach or way forward with this.

Comment: Are you inside the "TradeMe" firewalls, querying the internal database directly, or something else? If something else, can you explain how you are querying the information? Explaining your scenario with specific technical details will help people answer your question.

Comment: No, I'm just building a site similar to TradeMe. I'm looking for an approach. The main issue is how to catch an expiring auction in real-time as opposed to retrospectively via a scheduled task.

Comment: @Adam Cameron. Tried plenty of things. Researched plenty of things. Thanks for your helpful comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you've got a auctionClosesAt or auctionDuration column in your mySQL DB: could you programatically add a one-off scheduled task via cfschedule?

So when the auction gets initially created, part of what it does is create a cfschedule with the exact auction end time. i.e now + 7days

You'd have to set a normal scheduled task to remove expired scheduled tasks as well I'd imagine.

The other way you could do it is only make auctions end on exact intervals, i.e 5/10/15/20/25 etc minutes past the hour, and run the task at those exact times.

Comment: Those are nice ideas. I'll investigate them more.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's not really the database that will do this, but in general, this is how you would handle this:

Have a background process, daemon, or service (if Windows) that runs ALL the time. It will basically be a clock, but will also keep a queue of *UPCOMING* end times and schedule things to happen at precisely each auction's end time.

Now, you have to be able to "feed" this service each end time. Whatever you have that sets the end time for a new auction needs to somehow "signal" the service that there is a new end time to be aware of.

There are many ways to write daemons/services to "listen" for events, and many ways to have the auction-end-time-setter emit these events to tell the service about them. This answer will get really long if we cover the possibilities there, but essentially understand that you need an event source (the end time being set) and an event listener (the thing that schedules work to be done at each end-time).

You can always search for and/or post other questions if you want to get more detail about a certain facet of this.

Comment: Thanks for those ideas. Similar to Neokoenig's in the sense of scheduling events associated with the closing of a particular auction.